# py2neo: Why using class attributes?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

1. py2neo uses *class attributes* to model the attributes of nodes in neo4j.
   What is the reason (or underlying architecture/philosophy) for not using *instance attributes*?
2. Would there be an easy (generic) way to convert/map py2neo results (of type GraphObject) into objects with instance attributes?

Thank you for any hints or insights!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Attributes defined on the class can be overridden by attributes on sub-classes:

```
class A(object):
    x = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 2

class B(A):
    x = 11
    y = 22


b = B()
print(b.x, b.y)
```

will print

```
11 2
```

since the `x` is overridden when the class `B` is created, but then the `A.__init__()` method is ran which overwrites `self.y` with 2.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting example.

Comment: 'A.x' and 'B.x' are class attributes.
Yes, `B.y` is a class attribute too while `a.y` is an instance attribute. `B.y` is actually not overwritten but shadowed: You can still access its value in your last code line using `B.y` or `b.__class__.y`

Comment: My actual question was about the usage of class attributes in [py2neo](https://py2neo.org/v4/) for [OGM](https://py2neo.org/v4/ogm.html).